# Spawning Enemies not working in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to spawn enemies at random intervals but when i write the code commented below the screen turns to white and canvas is off and the enemies are spawned at random location instead at the top position declared.Please check the code commented and let me know what i am doing wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/rz7udd72/

}

```
// function animatePlanets() {
//     var time = Date.now();

//     if (time > lastSpawn + spawnTime) {
//         lastSpawn = time;
//         spawnPlanets();
//     }


//     canvasContext.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

//     for(var i=0; i < planets.length; i++){
//         var planet = planets[i];
//         planet.y += planetSpeedY;
//         canvasContext.beginPath();
//         canvasContext.arc(planet.x, planet.y, planetRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
//         canvasContext.fillStyle  = 'red';
//         canvasContext.fill();

//         canvasContext.closePath();
//     }

// }
```

Comment: well don't clear the canvas if you don't want to... (`ctx.clearRect(...`)

Comment: if i don't clear the canvas then it shows a trail of the objects. Plus it kind of breaks the canvas and a white background is shown.

Comment: You are already filling your canvas with black in `drawEverything`, so you really don't wnt to clear your canvas in the middle of the frame drawing like that : https://jsfiddle.net/rz7udd72/1/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But there's another problem you see that the red ball is being generated everywhere on the canvas however i am trying to spawn it on the top only and  anywhere on the width. Like i declared `planetY = 0` and `planetX = canvas.width * Math.random();`. What am i doing wrong in that?

Comment: well you need to not use globals `planetX` and `planetY` but rather to set it in your `spawnPlanets`

Comment: iam using them in `DrawEverything()` and `moveEverything()` that would cause errors if i don't declare them Globals.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rz7udd72/3/

Comment: Thanks alot man.